# Is there only one static variable between processes or each has its own?

Tags: c++, process

I have declared a static variable, and use the static variable in two processes.

Is there only one static variable between processes or each has its own?

---

I focus on multi processes, not for static variable syntax

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by `use the static variable in two processes`? If its two instances of the same application running, each has its own memory space.

Comment: not saying that it is the case here, but often processes are confused with threads and `static` has different meanings depending on context, so there is lots of room for misunderstanding. Though, someone already managed to give a good answer to something I thought cannot be answered with a good answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there only one static variable ...

Depends on context.

If it is a static **member** or a static variable in block scope then yes, there is only one instance.

If it is a static variable in namespace scope, then there are as many instances of the variable as there are translation units using the variable.

> ... between processes or each has its own?

The C++ language has no concept of a process. As such there is no such thing as a variable shared between processes in the language. When I say "only one instance" in the previous part, it effectively means same as "only one instance per process".

Comment: thanks for you answer, when I run two programs through linux shell command. it will create two processes. And each one have it's own memory space, so the static instance is per process. But if I create by thread, then the two threads will share the static instance?

Comment: Incidentally, a 16 bit DLL has the nice habit of sharing static variables between processes.